# Adding a ruled area for notes in beamer handouts?

Tags: beamer

I want to make a handout that has a ruled area for students to jot down notes. Here's how I envision this looking: there is a 2x2 array on each page with the left column being slides 1 and 2, while the right column consists of two separate ruled regions where students can write notes pertaining to the corresponding slide in the left column.

I was thinking that I could just use a mode specification like this:

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame Title}
Frame Contents
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}<handout>
\frametitle{Notes}
\hline
\hline
...
\hline
\end{frame}
```

This seems a bit clumsy to me, so do any of you know a better way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `\hline` isn't legal in that context.

Comment: Guido Diepen's [handoutWithNotes.sty](http://www.guidodiepen.nl/2009/07/creating-latex-beamer-handouts-with-notes/) package offers this funcionality.

Answer (score 3):

A bit less clumsy:

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}

\newcommand\notepage[2][16pt]{%
  \begin{frame}<handout>{Notes}
  \cleaders\vbox to #1{\kern#1\hrule width \textwidth\vss}\vskip#2\dimexpr#1\relax
  \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
  Frame Contents
\end{frame}

\notepage{6} % lined note page with controls

\notepage[12pt]{15}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not much less clumsy perhaps, but you could save a "template" of note page using `\newcommand` and (re-)use it after each of your actual slide.

```
\newcommand\lnd{\rule{\linewidth}{.5pt}\\}
\newcommand\notepg{
  \begin{frame}<handout>{Notes}
    \lnd\lnd\lnd\lnd\lnd\lnd\lnd\lnd\lnd\lnd\lnd\lnd\lnd
  \end{frame}
}
```

Then put `\notepg` after the actual slides.

If you'd like to have a bit more control, say varying the number lines in different note pages, or to change the spacing between lines, you can use the following:

```
\newcounter{numline}    
\newcommand\drawline[1]{\rule{\linewidth}{.5pt}\\[#1]\stepcounter{numline}}    
\newcommand\notepage[2][5pt]{
  \begin{frame}<handout>{Notes}
    \drawline{#1}
      \ifnum\value{numline}=#2 \else \drawline{#1}
      \ifnum\value{numline}=#2 \else \drawline{#1}
      \ifnum\value{numline}=#2 \else \drawline{#1}
      \ifnum\value{numline}=#2 \else \drawline{#1}
      \ifnum\value{numline}=#2 \else \drawline{#1}
      \ifnum\value{numline}=#2 \else \drawline{#1}
      \ifnum\value{numline}=#2 \else \drawline{#1}
      \ifnum\value{numline}=#2 \else \drawline{#1}
      \ifnum\value{numline}=#2 \else \drawline{#1}
      \ifnum\value{numline}=#2 \else \drawline{#1}
      \ifnum\value{numline}=#2 \else \drawline{#1}
      \ifnum\value{numline}=#2 \else \drawline{#1}  
    \fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi
  \end{frame}
}
```

This defines a command `\notepage[<line spacing>]{<num of lines>}`, which can be used the same way as `\notepg`, but allows you to control the spacing between lines (default value is `.5pt` is optional argument is not given) and the number of lines drawn on the note page.

## Full Code

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}

\newcommand\lnd{\rule{\linewidth}{.5pt}\\}
\newcommand\notepg{
  \begin{frame}<handout>{Notes}
    \lnd\lnd\lnd\lnd\lnd\lnd\lnd\lnd\lnd\lnd\lnd\lnd\lnd
  \end{frame}
}

\newcounter{numline}
\newcommand\drawline[1]{\rule{\linewidth}{.5pt}\\[#1]\stepcounter{numline}}
\newcommand\notepage[2][5pt]{
  \begin{frame}<handout>{Notes}
    \drawline{#1}
      \ifnum\value{numline}=#2 \else \drawline{#1}
      \ifnum\value{numline}=#2 \else \drawline{#1}
      \ifnum\value{numline}=#2 \else \drawline{#1}
      \ifnum\value{numline}=#2 \else \drawline{#1}
      \ifnum\value{numline}=#2 \else \drawline{#1}
      \ifnum\value{numline}=#2 \else \drawline{#1}
      \ifnum\value{numline}=#2 \else \drawline{#1}
      \ifnum\value{numline}=#2 \else \drawline{#1}
      \ifnum\value{numline}=#2 \else \drawline{#1}
      \ifnum\value{numline}=#2 \else \drawline{#1}
      \ifnum\value{numline}=#2 \else \drawline{#1}
      \ifnum\value{numline}=#2 \else \drawline{#1}  
    \fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi
  \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
  Frame Contents 
\end{frame}

\notepg % simply lined note page

\notepage[3pt]{12} % lined note page with controls
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image][image][image]